# Breathing with a bag on head

Tags: fluid-dynamics, air, biophysics, estimation, diffusion

I got into an interesting argument after seeing a image of someone protecting themselves from splattering oil from a frying pan with a plastic bag over themselves.

1. First question is: can a person breathe indefinitely inside a bag, given that it is loose?

We could simplify the problem to the bag being a cylinder with a hole in bottom and person breathing sideways, not downwards, from the top.

My reasoning is that, if the cylinder is wide enough compared to the height of the cylinder, carbon dioxide exhaled by the person will float down while new air comes up. The person would notice a higher CO<sub>2</sub> concentration but should be fine, as long as the cylinder is wide enough. And this width shouldn't be anywhere close to the height.

2. Also, if a person can breathe like that, how wide does the cylinder have to be in relation to the length?

Some assumptions regarding calculations:
Pressure is 1 atm.
A human loses consciousness at 10% CO<sub>2</sub> concentration (by volume).
Oxygen concentration has to be at least 18% by volume.
Oxygen and carbon dioxide concentrations of air are 21% and 0.04%, respectively.
A human uses 0.4 liters of oxygen per minute @ 1 atm.

The question can be boiled down to: How wide does the cylinder have to be for the carbon dioxide to diffuse and fall due to gravity and be replaced with oxygen rich air, so that the carbon dioxide concentration doesn't go too high for the person to faint?

Needless to say: **don't try this**, unless you are a professional that knows what they are doing and has done the needed safety precautions.

Edit: Changed the wording and added information for calculations.

Comment: Q1 "Can a person breathe indefinitely inside a loose fitting bag" seems to be more of a biology question than a physics question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be answered by simple common sense, if you put a bag over your head and it's big enough to let air in, you will be ok. If it's not, you won't.

Comment: See also Skeptics.SE's [Do children accidentally suffocate themselves with plastic bags?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6529/) for statistics and a link to a study which reviews "The circumstances of suffocation by plastic bags"

Comment: @pentane I'd think it's a physics question as the question is whether the bag will fill up with carbon dioxide or some other gas that would cause fainting or death. 
The Sceptics.SE: I feel this is a different question as the plastic bags in those cases are probably somehow sealed, so air can't circulate.

Comment: @CountTo10 There is the other question of how big the bag has to be for enough air to circulate.

Comment: "the plastic bags in those cases are probably somehow sealed" but look at the deaths: "25 reports a year describing deaths to children who suffocated due to plastic bags. Almost 90 percent of them were under one year of age." I can't imagine that those would be perfectly sealed bags. So I think there *is* a physics question buried here-- about gas diffusion rates. Moving the question away from biological criteria like death or fainting and towards gas concentration levels would help I think.

Comment: @pentane I have to admit, "somewhat sealed" would have been a better expression. 
The question is: How wide does the cylinder have to be for the carbon dioxide to diffuse and fall due to gravity and be replaced with oxygen rich air, so that the carbon dioxide concentration doesn't go too high for the person to faint. I will add the necessary biological information to the question to make this purely a physics one.

Comment: There are physics to this question, but the answers would have to come from engineering. Try researching "closed loop breathing apparatus" or "closed loop rebreathers" on the internet. For a closed or almost closed system, the practical, safe solution is to provide CO2 scrubbing materials in the line of flow and active replenishment of oxygen as it is depleted. Otherwise provide a fan. The process of diffusion, too slow to depend on for life support.